# haskell-mode-hook does only work on a single function

Tags: haskell, emacs, hook

I'm trying to configure `haskell-mode` by adding functions to the hook:

```
(add-hook 'haskell-mode-hook 'turn-on-haskell-indentation)
(add-hook 'haskell-mode-hook 'turn-on-haskell-doc-mode)
```

The problem is that it only works if I comment one statement out,
if I use the above code it tells my what the `haskell-mode-hook` was and what it now is and shows me the help text.

I'm using Emacs24 on Ubuntu 13.10.

Can someone please tell my why it doesn't work?
Thanks

Comment: It should call both functions (assuming they're both valid). Can you confirm that the two functions are compatible? If you call them manually in the same sequence (using `M-x`, and without your hook values present), is the end result different?

Comment: Ok, i just realized that these hook wasn't the problem. Sorry for using your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why this isn't working as you'd expect, but as a solution, can you just use a `lambda` function in the `add-hook` function? For example

```
  (add-hook 'haskell-mode-hook (lambda()
                                     (turn-on-haskell-indentation)
                                     (turn-on-haskell-docs-mode)))
```

Comment: I just installed haskell-mode - the function name in my version is turn-on-haskell-doc-mode, was that a typo in copying from emacs, or is that perhaps the root of your problem?

Answer (score 4):

Could this be a simple typo? I think `turn-on-haskell-docs-mode` should be `turn-on-haskell-doc-mode`.

Comment: It's a typo in the question.

Comment: Aha, okay. But the only difference between your example code and the lambda is that the two functions will be executed in a different order, because `add-hook` *prepends* functions to the hook list. So maybe there's a subtle dependency between the two functions.